# Print object in template_preprocess_page

Tags: 8

In `template_preprocess_page()` in my MYTHEME.theme file, I'm trying to validate if node has specific value.
When I `dpm($variables)` I get:

```
Array
(
    [node] => stdClass Object
    (
        [__CLASS__] => Drupal\node\Entity\Node
        [in_preview] => 
        [values] => Array
        (
            [vid] => Array
                (
                    [x-default] => 2
                )
...
    [page] => Array
    (
...
```

When I `dpm($variables['node'])` I get:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [__CLASS__] => Drupal\node\Entity\Node
    [in_preview] => 
    [values] => Array
        (
...
```

When I `dpm($variables['node']->values)` I get empty result.

**Why so?**

Comment: Maybe the array is empty?

Comment: Just edit my question. You can now see a `values` chunk. And no, it's not empty.

Comment: It's difficult to understand where this object is coming from - nodes are typed objects in D8, how come you're working with a `stdClass`?

Comment: Well, I just started with D8 so I was expecting it's working the same as in D7. How otherwise you'd get object values in case of D8?

Comment: Just so that you know, I didn't add any custom modules. Just core and devel module.

Comment: Gotcha, I always use kint which provides a better visual for vars but I can see my output's the same as yours with kint disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use :

dpm($variables['node']->toArray());

Comment: It does work this way, but my question is why it doesn't work with an object.

Comment: because the values property is a protected property of ContentEntityBase class and Node extends ContentEntityBase


https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!ContentEntityBase.php/property/ContentEntityBase%3A%3Avalues/8.2.x

Comment: In which case php would be throwing a _cannot access protected_  warning...if you're in a dev environment, make sure your error reporting is such that you'll see warnings like this, it'll be less painful to debug.

Answer (score 0):

And for better debug view I advise you to use "kint" instead! You can iterate better through your objects.